# Searching a single solution for sharing and "natting" a 3G internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, wireless-access-point, 3g

I need a single, easily configurable, preferably open source, and still complete solution to turn my laptop into a WiFi Access Point, Router and Firewall/NAT, and share its own 3G internet connection (seen by the OS like a dial-up connection).

OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which operating system is running on your laptop?

Assuming Windows 7 you might simply use the built-in internet conenction sharing:

- Go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center
- Under Change your networking settings, click Set up a new connection or network
- Select Set up a wireless ad hoc (computer-to-computer) network
- Enter your Network name, and enter a Security key if wanted
- Check the box for Save this network and click Turn on Internet connection sharing on next page

Comment: Windows 7. Thanks for your help (I upvoted) but this is not properly what I asked. I will do it as a temporary solution.

Comment: I see. You might take a look into virtualrouter (opensource) or Connectivity (the light version is free). But if you want a more configurable solution e.g. with configurable firewall rules, I'm out of ideas.